# Re-open advanced disclosure from different countries

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/103604/i-am-from-northern-ireland-but-live-in-scotland-and-need-to-complete-an-advanc/) was closed due to being company specific or requiring a lawyer to answer. However that's not the case and I'd like to request we open it.

The question is referring to criminal records checks, which is a national certificate in the UK but can be obtained from different bodies and has different rules depending on the level of criminal records check required. This is not a company specific entity. The only thing company specific is what level of check they may way to conduct.

It doesn't require a lawyer, any HR representative or admin person who has dealt with them is aware of the process and how they work (I've dealt with them as a Scout member).

Answer (score 2):

I'm with you on this one - re-open vote cast.

Comment: me too ;) vote casted